# HTML data attributes on the same page are not working for countdown script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I used this script: http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html
I have more than one 'data-time' attributes on the same page like you see in the code.

The first data-time attribute is 17 nov and the second one gives data-time attribute 18 nov:

```
<!-- 1st block -->                            
<div class="kf_event_list_wrap">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-5 col-sm-5">
                                    <!--EVENT LIST THUMB Start-->
                                    <div class="kf_event_list_thumb">
                                        <figure>
                                            <img src="extra-images/event_1.jpg" alt=""/>
                                            <div id="defaultCountdown" data-time="nov 17, 2016 12:00:00" class="defaultCountdown"></div>
                                        </figure>
                                    </div>
                                    <!--EVENT LIST THUMB END-->
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-7 col-sm-7">
                                    <!--EVENT LIST DES Start-->
                                    <div class="kf_event_list_des">
                                        <h4><a href="#">University <span>Convocation</span></a></h4>
                                        <p>Mauris in erat justo. Nullam ac urna eu felis dapibus condimentum sit amet a augue. Sed non neque elit. Sed ut imperdiet nisie tiam pharetra, erat sed fermentum feugiat, velit mauris egestas quam.</p>
                                        <ul class="kf_event_list_links">
                                            <li><i class="fa fa-user"></i><a href="#">John Doe</a></li>
                                            <li><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i><a href="#">Saturday 10:00 AM</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                    <!--EVENT LIST DES END-->
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>




<!-- 2th block -->
<div class="kf_event_list_wrap">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-5 col-sm-5">
                                    <!--EVENT LIST THUMB Start-->
                                    <div class="kf_event_list_thumb">
                                        <figure>
                                            <img src="extra-images/event_1.jpg" alt=""/>
                                            <div id="defaultCountdown" data-time="nov 18, 2016 12:00:00" class="defaultCountdown"></div>
                                        </figure>
                                    </div>
                                    <!--EVENT LIST THUMB END-->
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-7 col-sm-7">
                                    <!--EVENT LIST DES Start-->
                                    <div class="kf_event_list_des">
                                        <h4><a href="#">University <span>Convocation</span></a></h4>
                                        <p>Mauris in erat justo. Nullam ac urna eu felis dapibus condimentum sit amet a augue. Sed non neque elit. Sed ut imperdiet nisie tiam pharetra, erat sed fermentum feugiat, velit mauris egestas quam.</p>
                                        <ul class="kf_event_list_links">
                                            <li><i class="fa fa-user"></i><a href="#">John Doe</a></li>
                                            <li><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i><a href="#">Saturday 10:00 AM</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                    <!--EVENT LIST DES END-->
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

But now, the javascript code:

```
    if($('.defaultCountdown').length){
        var date1 = $('#defaultCountdown').data('time');
        var date = new Date(date1);
        $('.defaultCountdown').countdown({ until: date}); 
    }
```

Now i have a problem that the timer is showing the same countdown. Maybe because the id is the same on the 2 blocks?

I thought that there was something wrong with my javascript and i searched for something else but its also not working. I don't know of this is in the right direction:

```
if($('.defaultCountdown').length){
$('[data-time]').each(function() {
   var $this = $('.defaultCountdown'), finalDate = $(this).data('time');
   $this.countdown(finalDate, function(event) {

     var date = new Date(finalDate);
     $('.defaultCountdown').countdown({ until: date});
   });
});
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will work:

```
$('[data-time]').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this), finalDate = new Date($(this).data('time'));
    $this.countdown({ until: finalDate}); 
    // or all in one line
    // $(this).countdown({ until: new Date($(this).data('time'))});
});
```

I think that the problem with what you've tried is that you were using:

```
$('.defaultCountdown').countdown({ until: date});
```

Instead of:

```
$this.countdown({ until: date});
```

You were setting the `countdown` to all the elements with class `defautlCountdown` instead of setting it to the current element `$this`.

Comment: The timer is the same on all elements now but its a wrong countdown. So if i switch on the first block the date-time to Nov 18 and the second date-time to Nov 20 it is the same countdown what's is wrong and from today it gives 34 minutes and not the days. So it's not good. Any other solution? I don't know of the javascript is correct here.

Comment: @Brecht27 I've changed my answer to convert the `date-time` `String` value to a `Date` object. Give it a try now to see if it works.

Comment: Thats it! Thanks for helping me out here! +1